# Prove that $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathscr P(B) \implies \bigcup \mathcal F \subseteq B$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $\mathcal F$ is family of sets and $B$ is a set. Prove that if $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathscr P(B)$ then $\bigcup \mathcal F \subseteq B$

My attempt:

Let $x$ be in $\bigcup \mathcal F$. It follows that there must be some set, call it $A$, such that $A \in \mathcal F$ and $x \in A$. Since $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathscr P(B)$, it follows that $A \in \mathscr P(B)$, and by definition of the power set, we can conclude that $A \subseteq B$. And since $x \in A$, $x\in B$. Because $x$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that $\forall x  (x \in \bigcup \mathcal F \implies x \in B)$, hence $\bigcup F \subseteq B$. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: Seeing how you've asked quite a few questions like this today, perhaps it would be instructive to ask you now. Where do you think your proof was wrong? What point did you think was a subtle point where you maybe made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, clear and correct.

Just a minor style thing, just so you have some feedback to actually do something with ;) Personally I don't like big first-order formulas in text. In your case you have $\forall x(x \in \bigcup \mathcal{F} \implies x \in B)$ in there. Either you can put it in display mode:
$$
\forall x(x \in \bigcup \mathcal{F} \implies x \in B),
$$
or simply do not use these formulas at all. In this case you actually just leave it out entirely, or if you really want replace it with a sentence like

> ... conclude that every element of $\bigcup \mathcal{F}$ is also in $B$, hence ...